# How to convert rate from any currency to base currency in magento 2

Tags: magento2, currency

```
class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_currencyFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory,
        ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_currencyFactory = $currencyFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    function convertRate(){
        $quoteAmmount = 15;
        $baseCurrencyCode = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseCurrency()->getCode();
        $quoteCurrency = 'CAD';
        $rateToBase = $this->_currencyFactory->create()->load($quoteCurrency)->getAnyRate($baseCurrencyCode);
        $totalAmount = $quoteAmmount * $rateToBase;
    }
}
```

This is my custom code and I want to convert my CAD quote price to my store base currency which is USD. But this code returned 0.
What is the problem?

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this below code :

```
class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_priceCurrency;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data $priceCurrency,
        ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    function convertRate(){
        $quoteAmmount = 15;
        $rate = $this->_priceCurrency->currency($quoteAmmount, true, true);
        return $rate;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not working for me :(

Comment: Is there any error or system.log ?

Comment: No, but amount is not converting. As per my requirement i am having 15 CAD and want to convert it in USD. But above code is returning 15 without any change

Comment: Check my updated answer. remove var/ generated or generation folder.

Comment: In above code where we tell from currency and to currency ?

Comment: It will automatically consider price as per store vise.

Comment: getting this error : `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Directory\Model\PriceCurrency::currency()`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `vendor/magento/module-directory/Helper/Data.php`

```
public function currencyConvert($amount, $from, $to = null)
{
    if (empty($this->_currencyCache[$from])) {
        $this->_currencyCache[$from] = $this->_currencyFactory->create()->load($from);
    }
    if ($to === null) {
        $to = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
    }
    $converted = $this->_currencyCache[$from]->convert($amount, $to);
    return $converted;
}
```

I think you can use this function:

```
$this->directoryHelper->currencyConvert($quoteAmmount, $quoteCurrencyCode, $baseCurrencyCode);
```

Comment: i am getting this error : Undefined rate from \"CAD-USD\"

Comment: Seems that we need to set the rate: *STORES  > Currency Rates*

Comment: should i import these rates manually or is there any way to set them programmatically ??

Comment: You can set these rates manually, just press the import button. We can set the cron job on configuration: *STORES > Configuration > General > Currency Setup > Scheduled Import Settings *

Comment: i add rate manually for CAD but getting same error : Undefined rate from \"CAD-USD\"

Comment: I should work. Try to clear cache.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85369/discussion-between-iqbal-malik-and-khoa-truongdinh).